# How to create a new column with the last value of the previous year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'COTA':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
   'Date':['14/10/2021','19/10/2020','29/10/2019','30/09/2021','20/09/2020','20/10/2021','29/10/2020','15/10/2019','10/09/2020'],         
   'Mark':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,3]
  })
print(df)
```

based on this data frame I wanted the `MARK` from the previous year, I managed to acquire the maximum `COTA` but I wanted the last one, I used `.max()` and I thought I could get it with `.last()` but it didn't work.

follow the example of my code.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['LastYear'] = df['Date'] - pd.offsets.YearEnd(0)

s1 = df.groupby(['Found', 'LastYear'])['Mark'].max()
s2 = s1.rename(index=lambda x: x + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1), level=1)

df = df.join(s2.rename('Max_MarkLastYear'), on=['Found', 'LastYear'])
print (df)

   Found      Date  Mark   LastYear  Max_MarkLastYear
0     A 2021-10-14     1 2021-12-31               5.0
1     A 2020-10-19     2 2020-12-31               3.0
2     A 2019-10-29     3 2019-12-31               NaN
3     A 2021-09-30     4 2021-12-31               5.0
4     A 2020-09-20     5 2020-12-31               3.0
5     B 2021-10-20     1 2021-12-31               3.0
6     B 2020-10-29     2 2020-12-31               3.0
7     B 2019-10-15     3 2019-12-31               NaN
8     B 2020-10-09     3 2020-12-31               3.0
```

How do I create a new column with the last value of the previous year

Comment: _"How do I create a new column with the last value of the previous year"_ - that's not very clear. Can you add a dataframe containing your expected output to the question?

Comment: What means `didn't work`? If you get error then show it in question (not in comments). We don't have your data, we can't run your code, and we can't read in your mind - you have to put all details in question. And would be better if you would put example data as DataFrame and show expected result for these data.

Comment: in code you try to get from column `Found` but you don't have it in data and you don't create this column. This raise error.

Comment: to get last by date then you should sort by date